# AngularJS Animate - First hide the list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I'm quite new at Angular and I am trying to create a small fadeIN/OUT animation for lists.

I have two lists, which i can toggle with a button on the top of the page. When a new list is coming, there is a small animation for fade-in and fade-out.

```
Please see following Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/A8Aozfq2fHuUKQFaJm7l?p=preview
```

My problem is, that i want a "serial workflow". So when the first list is hided, then should come the second one - At the moment, there is a "parallel workflow". So how can i change that ?

Comment: I use `ng-style` for this kind of situations instead of `ng-hide`/`ng-show`.

Comment: thanks for your input - but if you use ng-style, there is still the same problem that there is a 'parallel fade effect' and not a serial one ?!

Comment: Making it `display:none;` by default would solve that (by that I mean in you css). :)

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing transition time. It can help.

Comment: Use comments for suggestions like this. It's not an answer to the question.